# How to check Friendship in Pokemon Legends: Arceus?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Usually there's an NPC that lets you check the Friendship level with your Pokemon.
Is there one in Pokemon Legends: Arceus, too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. His name is Belamy, and can be found near the Pasture after meeting Kleavor. You need to completed the [Measuring Your Compatibility](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/requests/measuringyourcompatibility.shtml) request.

[image]

From now on, Belamy will offer up the ability to check how much your Pokémon like you.

Here's a table with the phrases you get and the relative Friendship level:

| Statement | Values |
| --- | --- |
| You and Pokémon are as friendly as can be! You must simply adore each other's company! | 255 |
| What an excellent pair of friends you and Pokémon make. You must mean a lot to each other! | 200-254 |
| You and Pokémon seem to be fast friends. You must be quite good companions! | 150-199 |
| Pokémon seems to get on well with you. But I'm sure it could get on better! | 100-149 |
| I suppose Pokémon's become a bit friendly toward you, but you've a ways to go... | 50-89 |
| Pokémon seems leery of you yet. New to the team, perhaps? | 0-49 |

Usually, a Friendship level of 160 it's enough to evolve a Pokemon.

---

Additionally, these activities can boost your Pokemon Friendship level:

- Level up a Pokemon
- Win a battle
- Use a Pokémon to break Ore
- Use a Pokémon to shake a tree
- Use a Pokémon to shake a Box

Comment: What causes the "Look how pleased" message in the screenshot?

Comment: @Malady that's the response you get after showing him the Pokemon needed for  "Measuring Your Compatibility" request I mentioned above: he wants you to show him that you can befriend Pokémon.